# How do I flatten 3 records into one in Teradata?

Tags: arrays, teradata, flatten

I have a Teradata query that will output a maximum of three different types of data in a common field into 3 separate records.  I am currently using a Case statement to break those common fields into unique fields, however, the output is still 3 records per person.

This is the output of the current Case statement described in the next section:

**I have images that show the current set of data but don't have the reputation points to be able to post them.**

Here is the current Case statement that achieves the result of getting each set of test information into the correct columns based on the Test Name:

```
,CASE WHEN Test = 'Biology' THEN BiologyName ELSE null END As "Biology Test Name"
,CASE WHEN Test = 'Biology' THEN BiologyDate ELSE null END as "Biology Test Date"
,CASE WHEN Test = 'Biology' THEN BiologyResult ELSE null END as "Biology Test Result"

,CASE WHEN Test = 'Calculus' THEN CalculusName ELSE null END As "Calculus Test Name"
,CASE WHEN Test = 'Calculus' THEN CalculusDate ELSE null END as "Calculus Test Date"
,CASE WHEN Test = 'Calculus' THEN CalculusResult ELSE null END as "Calculus Test Result"

,CASE WHEN Test = 'Language Arts' THEN LanguageArtsName ELSE null END As "LA Test Name"
,CASE WHEN Test = 'Language Arts' THEN LanguageArtsDate ELSE null END as "LA Test Date"
,CASE WHEN Test = 'Language Arts' THEN LanguageArtsResult ELSE null END as "LA Test Result"
```

Consider the following image where the data on the left (Cols A-D) is the current output and Cols F-O is the desired output:

**I have images that show the current set of data but don't have the reputation points to be able to post them.**

Comment: Here's the image showing how the code above would currently output:

https://yapics.com/a4203udz904

Consider the following image where the data on the left (Cols A-D) is the current output without the Case Statement and Cols F-O is the desired output:

https://yapics.com/a4203jGQ904

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close :-)

Simply `GROUP BY name` and apply MAX:

```
,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Biology' THEN BiologyName END) AS "Biology Test Name"
,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Biology' THEN BiologyDate END) AS "Biology Test Date"
,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Biology' THEN BiologyResult END) AS "Biology Test Result"

,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Calculus' THEN CalculusName END) AS "Calculus Test Name"
,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Calculus' THEN CalculusDate END) AS "Calculus Test Date"
,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Calculus' THEN CalculusResult END) AS "Calculus Test Result"

,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Language Arts' THEN LanguageArtsName END) AS "LA Test Name"
,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Language Arts' THEN LanguageArtsDate END) AS "LA Test Date"
,Max(CASE WHEN Test = 'Language Arts' THEN LanguageArtsResult END) AS "LA Test Result"
```

There's no need for `ELSE NULL`, it's the default anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your response, dnoeth!  I'll give that a try.  Re: Else Null, I thought that was the case.  However, when I used my ETL tool to flatten, I had to first change the  blank entry to null before it would work, so I thought there must be something in that field.  I'm checking now...

Comment: You're probably able to predict my next question as I received a SELECT Failed [3504] error on the Group By clause.

In my dataset, I have 4 different identifiers and I have picked the appropriate identifier for grouping in the scenario and added "GROUP BY AppID" to the query.  I noticed you mentioned "Group By name", assuming the UID for this one was a name field but that should work the same for a numerical identifier, correct?  What am I missing?

Comment: Hmmmm...It seems like I need to use a provide a Group By clause for each join statement.  Is that correct?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the actual Select, but you need to add *all* non-aggregated colums in your Select-list to Group By.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I upvoted your answer as, when I remove all the joins and and only output one column and then group by that column, it works.  I'll probably end up running that query separately and then joining to it based on that UID.  Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Yeo, that's probably the most efficient way, aggregate before join.